# Unexpected border pattern in a grid with rectangles in p5.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, processing, p5.js

I am trying to generate a square grid like pattern in p5js that covers as much of the browser window as possible.I am using p5js in instance mode as I using this with react and I am using chrome in Win10.
Here is my code:-

```
var size = 15;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

Sketch = (p) => {
        p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(width,height)
            p.frameRate(60);
            p.noLoop();
        } 

        p.draw = () => {
            p.background(250);
            p.stroke(0);
            p.noFill();
            for(let i =0;i*size +size <width;i++) {
                for(let j=0;j*size +size<height;j++) {
                    p.rect(i*size,j*size,size,size);
                }
            }
        }

        p.mouseDragged = (e) => {
            p.stroke(0);
            let x = Math.floor(e.clientY/size);
            let y = Math.floor(e.clientX/size);
            p.fill(220);
            p.rect(y*size,x*size,size,size);
                
        }
}
```

I call p.noLoop() so it doesnt refreshes everytime and I also have a button that calls p.redraw() to change everything to default. Here is the grid and behaviour I get:

[image: Bad Borders]

The borders of grids are of varying sizes, first they decrease then increase then decrease and so on. Also, the area around which I drag my mouse has even more weird borders(This gets resolved when I click somewhere else so is this a GPU Aliasing rendering issue?). How do I create grid with same borders throughout my screen?

Edit: When I render even a single box, it has issues. The left and upper border are fine. However the right and down borders have an extra pixel of grayish borders which seems to be the problem. How do I fix this?

[image: Single Box]

Also, How does strokeWeight and rect work in p5js? If I do strokeWeight(10) and rect(3,2,50,50), does that create a 50 by 50 rectangle with 10 pixels borders all around or the borders are included in the rectangle size?

Comment: Could it be that some other code is messing things up? I cannot reproduce your problems: https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/z_eNzf6aS

Comment: When I execute your provided code, same thing happens again for me. If its not happening to you, then is there a problem with my GPU Anti-aliasing or a browser problem? Also can you provide a screenshot of what you can see? Edit: I checked in MS Edge, the varying border width problem still exists for me there.

Comment: Even a single box has issue for me. I have linked the picture in the  question with some edits.I tried running this with a different laptop, and borders were still thicker than 1 pixel, the pattern of increasing and decreasing borders was not present however.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Windows and Chrome.